# window size jquery bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

While trying to create a single page template with parallax scrolling I found and odd problem. I'm am suspecting that the problem is in either the jQuery portion of maybe even the CSS it self, but I am rather not sure.

My current jQuery code bit reads the window size of the visitors browser and adjusts the height of the slides for each different anchored page. This way I achieved full with backgrounds no matter the window size. But in same time I realized that If I add different CSS components, they will not expand the active anchor background height, but rather will overflow onto the other slide.

Here is the jQuery portion responsible for the slides height

```
 $(function () {
     $('.windows').css({
         'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'
     });

     $(window).resize(function () {
         $('.windows').css({
             'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'
         });
     });

 });
```

And here is the site URL https://docstax.net/esgh/

Go to Plans and resize your browser you will see what I mean by not adjusting the high of slide based on needed high of content inside.

Edit: As suggested by putvande there where way to many $(window) which I was aware of, do to that I updated and minimized the code.

Comment: Why are there so many `(` around `$(window).height()`? And you know you can add all those elements as a comma separated string into the jQuery selector right?

Comment: @putvande It was rather a noobish fault, I could have binded the $(window) call to a single class lets say class="window" and attached that to <section id="plans" class="window"></section> I will fix that. Sorry for the noobish mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you don't want to manually add a height component to the div if the content is going to be too large for the container. Here's what I think would work:

```
   $(window).bind("load", function()                                                                                                                                                                                        
     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
         var windowHeight = $(window).height();                                                                                                                                                                        
         $('.windows').each(function(index) {                                                                                                                                                                          
           if ($(this).height() < windowHeight) {                                                                                                                                                                      
             $(this).height(windowHeight);                                                                                                                                                                             
           }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         }); 
         $(window).resize(function() {
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();                                                                                                                                                                        
            $('.windows').each(function(index) {                                                                                                                                                                          
               if ($(this).height() < windowHeight) {                                                                                                                                                                      
                  $(this).height(windowHeight);                                                                                                                                                                             
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            });
          });
      });
```

Comment: I did :) I simply added windows class so its <section id="plans" class="windows"></section> now :)

Comment: ok so I'll change the selector in the answer real quick to reflect that

Comment: Alright, I did update it to your code snipt but now its no longer full backgrounds for other sections. Refer to link attached in original question

Comment: I plugged this new version into your code and it looks right. You have to check each separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    $('.windows') .css({'height': height+'px'});
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var reheight = window.innerHeight;
        $('.windows') .css({'height': reheight+'px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is still there, try going to the link and scale your browser window you will see that the pricing tables overflow into bottom as the Plans section is resized to adjust for the new window height.

Comment: maybe you used fixed height or fixed margin inner element of plan section so when section size resized they doesn't resize. so you need more flexible style for inner element of plan

Answer (score 0):

I tried your page, I'm failing to see a problem :
The sections are resized as they should. Content is display as it should considering the styles applied.
When a section is smaller than its content, the content starts bleeding out on other pages. Perfectly normal. You could set  `overflow: hidden;` on your `.windows` to prevent that from happening and/or use media queries to resize the content.

Here is a lighter function by the way, just edited your code :

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.windows').css({ 'height': $(window).height() });
    }).resize();
});
```

No need to write the code twice : setting the resize handler and triggering it manually should do.
Write it once, so when you need to change it, you'll change it only once.
You could also reset de scrollTop in your resize handler to keep focus on the same portion of the page.

Comment: 2 problems: The first is that it appears MemeCat has disappeared and no longer wants to acknowledge this question. The second is that your answer pretends that there isn't a much better way to address this problem. The content shouldn't bleed out of the container if you're not setting the height of the container too small. Checking within the JS code ensures that this won't happen.

Comment: To me, the problem does not appear to be the js code, it looks like MemeCat was trying to fit content that take more space than its container.
That's what you said and I think it was pretty much what I said : "When a section is smaller than its content, the content starts bleeding out".
Just commented the js code while I was here : MemeCat's code defines the same function twice, mine does not, I think it's enough improvement to post an answer.

Comment: I did not say or implied there was no better to deal with this problem than this piece of js code.
Read my answer, I said just the opposite. Not clearly enough obviously.